# Converse to a proposition on algebraically closed fields

Tags: field-theory

This is a follow up to a previous question. Let us call a field $F$ root-closed if every element $x$ of $F$ has at least one $n$-th root for every positive integer $n$. It is very easy to show that every algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ is root-closed. Is the converse true? That is, is every root-closed field of characteristic $0$ algebraically closed?

Comment: @reuns Don't you only need $\overline{F}$ to be a prosolvable extension (i.e. every finite quotient of the absolute Galois group by a closed subgroup is solvable)? I think there are such groups that are not abelian. But I might be wrong, my Galois theory is rusty!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sure, my comment was nonsense, $\overline{F}$ is the root closure of $F$ iff $\overline{F}/F$ is a tower of abelian extensions

Comment: @reuns I still think your comment was useful: that the answer is yes for certain fields, i.e. any finite field. [According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosolvable_group), another example is the $p$-adics $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Was wondering about when it is yes or no, there is an article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220000117 (it is for $F^{sep}/F$ but it should still help)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abel's impossibility theorem explicitly says "no". For instance, start with $K_0 = \Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb C$. Then recursively define $K_i$ as the extension of $K_{i-1}$ by all roots of all polynomials of the form $x^n - k$, for $k\in K_{i-1}$. The union of all these $K_i$ will be a root-closed subfield of $\Bbb C$ (it is the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ where each non-zero element has all its $n$ $n$-th roots). It consists exactly of all complex numbers that can be reached from the rational numbers by some finite application of the four standard arithmetic operations as well as taking complex $n$-th roots.

Abel's theorem says that there are polynomials over the rationals whose roots are impossible to describe in this form. One such polynomial is $x^5-x-1$.